# How to cast an ArrayList of objects to float in Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing

```java
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < a.size(), i++)

{

    float f = float(a.get(i));  // ERROR : cant convert Object to float

}
```

Comment: You might get better answers if you tag your question with the language and platform, rather than 'processing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) is a simpler java, so you can use the java syntax:

```
ArrayList<Float> a = new ArrayList<Float>();

a.add(1.0f); // "Autobox" a float into a Float object, adding it to the array

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    float f = a.get(i); // "Unbox" the Float object
}
```

Lookup [autoboxing/unboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Must not be .NET, otherwise would be i < a.count;

float f = (float)(a.get(i));  ??